# Understanding templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying run the following program, But it generates compilation error:

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_SUM_H_
#define TEMPLATE_SUM_H_

template<typename T>
class sum
{
  public:
    sum() {
      val_1 = 0;
      val_2 = 0;
    }
    sum(T a, T b) {
      val_1 = a;
      val_2 = b;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const sum<> &);

  private:
    T val_1, val_2;
    T result() const;
};

#endif
```

Source file:

```
include <iostream>
#include "inc/sum.h"

template<typename T>
T sum<T>::result() const {
   return (val_1 + val_2);
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const sum<T>& obj) {
//std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, sum<T>& obj) {
  os << obj.result();
  return os;
}

int main()
{
    sum<int> int_obj(15, 15);
    sum<float> float_obj(5.2, 3.5);
    std::cout << "result of int = " << int_obj << std::endl;
    std::cout << "result of float = " << float_obj << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with **g++ (4.4.3)** it generates following error:

```
In file included from template.cpp:2:
inc/sum.h:18: error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1)
inc/sum.h:5: error: provided for ‘template<class T> class sum’
template.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const sum<T>&) [with T = int]’:
template.cpp:20:   instantiated from here
template.cpp:5: error: ‘T sum<T>::result() const [with T = int]’ is private
template.cpp:12: error: within this context
template.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const sum<T>&) [with T = float]’:
template.cpp:21:   instantiated from here
template.cpp:5: error: ‘T sum<T>::result() const [with T = float]’ is private
template.cpp:12: error: within this context
```

1) Can Anyone please help me in identifying the error ?
Also Please suggest some links where I can find brief absolute details on how to use templates in c++.

2) I read that templatized func/classes declared in header file, and defined separately are prone to linking error. Can anyone explain/elaborate this ?
Is there any possibility of linking error in above example ?

The statement is as below:

"If a template or inline function is declared in a .h file, define it in that same file. The definitions of these constructs must be included into every .cpp file that uses them, or the program **may fail to link in some build configurations**."

This example can be done in some more easy way, without using overloaded operator etc. But I am trying to learn/practising templates and experimenting some features.

Comment: Look at that `friend` declaration again, `sum<>` what? The other errors is probably just follow up error because of this first one.

Comment: Also, read [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/440558).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I suppose it will take/use the template declaration of class. If I use it sum<T> than it was giving compilation error: ` **inc/sum.h:19: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const sum<T>&)’ declares a non-template function inc/sum.h:19: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) /tmp/cc1Ks86b.o: In function `main' `**.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for sharing this sueful link, It's answered all the questions asserted by me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a separate template definition for the `friend` function declaration:

```
template<typename U>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const sum<U> &);
```

`friend` declarations do not *inherit* the template parameters of the enclosing class.

Comment: That indeed solved the compilation error, Can you please explain why this is required ?

Comment: Hope that clarifies a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

A simple sample source, to get started;

> Calculator.h

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

template <class TYPE>
class Calculator{

public:
    Calculator();
    TYPE Sum(TYPE param1, TYPE param2);

};


/**
 * To avoid template related compilation error
 * when templates are used in header and source files
 *
 * This class file has been removed from the project-source file.
 * However, is present in the project folder
 * Gets compiled with the header-file (being included)
 */
#include "Calculator.cpp"

#endif
```

> Calculator.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Calculator.h"


template <class TYPE>
Calculator<TYPE>::Calculator()
{
}

template <class TYPE>
TYPE Calculator<TYPE>::Sum(TYPE param1, TYPE param2){

    cout << "Calculator::sum" << endl;
    cout << param1 <<endl;
    cout << param2 <<endl;

    TYPE result = param1 + param2 ;

    return result;
}
```

> Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Calculator.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello, Calculator!\n";

    Calculator<int> cObj;
    int out = cObj.Sum(2,3);
    cout << "out : " << out << endl;

    Calculator<string> cObjS;
    string outS = cObjS.Sum("A", "B");
    cout << "outS : " << outS << endl;

    cout << "Bye, Calculator!\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, you can refer to the [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp), to know about how to keep the template source and header contents, and knowing about how to fix the compilation and linker issues (with reasons).